# SimpleSAMLPHP: because it isn't a valid IdP for this SP

Tags: php, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

i am getting the following error when i am redirecting back from idp to saml-sp.

```
SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
0 /var/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:180 (N/A)
Caused by: SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Cannot retrieve metadata for IdP 'https://openidp.feide.no' because it isn't a valid IdP for this SP.
```

I tried to change metadata `'https://openidp.feide.no'` to `'http://192.168.0.105:81'.` But still the issue is not resolved. Could someone suggest any idea to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

There should be an entry like following inside metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php file
 for the 'issuer' value coming inside the SAMLResponse:

```
$metadata['https://openidp.feide.no'] = array( <config data removed for brevity> );
```

Also, within config/authsources.php you should point to that 'issuer' value inside your respective SP's configuration.

```
'sp1' => array(
        'idp' => 'https://openidp.feide.no', 
         <other config data removed for brevity>
),
```

Comment: I have done exactly this but still getting the same error :-/